# OpenCV Python remove small contours, save child contours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm attempting to remove all but the largest contours while retaining the child contours within the largest contour. Effectively I want to go from here: [Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS0L9.jpg) to: [Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c23rJ.jpg) I don't know how to go about this though (I'm not a programmer by any stretch and had help putting together the below). The code I do have doesn't retain the child contours. [Output of Below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSBH3.jpg)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('small_contour.jpg')
image_contours = np.zeros((img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 1), np.uint8)

image_binary = np.zeros((img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 1), np.uint8)

for channel in range(img.shape[2]):
    ret, image_thresh = cv.threshold(img[:, :, channel], 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)    
    contours = cv.findContours(image_thresh, 1, 1)[0]   
    cv.drawContours(image_contours, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 3)

contours = cv.findContours(image_contours, cv.RETR_LIST,
                           cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

cv.drawContours(image_binary, [max(contours, key = cv.contourArea)],
                -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv.imwrite('fill_contour.jpg', image_binary)
cv.imshow('Small Contour', image_binary)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code does in this line `cv.drawContours(image_binary, [max(contours, key = cv.contourArea)], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)` is to set to color `(255, 255, 255)` the pixels of the `image_binary` corresponding to the boundary and inner pixels of the bigger contour found by `cv.findContours`.

Creating the `image_binary` you are also swapping width with height and this is an error.

You don't need to keep the children: you should use `cv.RETR_TREE` for that, then find the index of the father and look for all contours with that father doing it recursively for the nested contours (children of children ...). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html But this is not useful for your goal.

---

You can use the result you currently have as a mask for the original image, but the code need some fixes, starting from the linked image named `VS0L9.jpg`.
Note that I'm using `cv2`, just change to `cv`.

Load the image

```
im = cv2.imread('VS0L9.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Find the contours (I used RETR_TREE)

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Find the bigger contour:

```
bigger = max(contours, key=lambda item: cv2.contourArea(item))
```

Initialize the mask (what you tried with `image_binary`):

```
the_mask = np.zeros_like(im)
```

Draw the fill the bigger contour on the mask image, the region of interest is set to (255, 255, 255):

```
cv2.drawContours(the_mask, [bigger], -1, (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)
```

At this point the mask looks like the output of your code, but with proper width and height.
Use the mask with the original image to show only the area of interest:

```
res = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask = the_mask)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
res = im.copy()
res[the_mask == 0] = 0
```

Now `res` is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use morphological reconstruction, with  erode image as marker.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('VS0L9.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (17,17))
kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
marker = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel,iterations = 5)
while True:
    tmp=marker.copy()
    marker=cv2.dilate(marker, kernel2)
    marker=cv2.min(thresh, marker)
    difference = cv2.subtract(marker, tmp)
    if cv2.countNonZero(difference) == 0:
        break

cv2.imwrite('out.png', marker)
cv2.imshow('result', marker )
```

[image]